# Summing up values for rows per columns starting with 'Col'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df =
  Col1  Col2  T3  T5
  ------------------
  28    34    11  22
  45    589   33  66
```

For each row I want to sum up the total values of columns whose names start with `Col`.
Is there some more elegant and quick way than the one shown below?

```
df['total'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    total_for_row = 0
    for column_name, column in df.transpose().iterrows():
        if 'Col' in column_name:
            total_for_row = total_for_row + row[column_name]
    row['total'] = total_for_row
```

Comment: In this case `df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Col')]].sum(axis=1)` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
idx = df.columns.str.startswith('Col')
df['total'] = df.iloc[:,idx].sum(axis=1)
```